# I have a problem rotating a 2D game object after collision

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I'm developing a simple flip game where a cube flips and the bar a it collides with should start rotating after collision. Most snips involve destroying an object, but that's not my case.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckI : MonoBehaviour
{
    float x;
    public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "bar")
        {
            x += Time.deltaTime * -10;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, x);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I start rotation after collision?

Comment: I added some pseudocode to your other question (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134372/). Please don't post duplicate questions as it just clutters the archive.

Answer (score 1):

[`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) is only called **once**, when the collider first makes contact with the object.

[`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) is the time that it took to complete the last frame, in seconds. This is almost always a very small number, so you're probably not noticing a very large change. You'll have to multiply this by a relatively large number if you want your change to be instantaneous.

If you want it to happen over time, you can use `OnCollisionEnter2D` to change a `bool`, and then apply your rotation in the `Update` method if `bool == true`.

Comment: You can also run `OnCollisionEnter` as a coroutine, and add `yield` statements to spread the execution across multiple frames after the collision occurs.